# VB.NET: How to Take MenuIDs those Loaded From Resource Dll

Tags: vb.net, menu, resources, wndproc, mainmenu

I have mainMenu at my own Resource-DLL and I put that to my Windows Form As MainMenu by API Methods: (LoadMenu and SetMenu)

**How can I take MenuIDs After Clicking with WndProc?**

```
 Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        If m.Msg = &H11F And m.LParam <> HMainMenu Then
            If m.LParam <> 0 Then
                MenuID = GetMenuItemID(m.LParam, 0)
                Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Selected.")
            Else
                Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Clicked. " & MenuID.ToString)
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
```

This statement give the ID as Wrong.

---

Hi there,
I find a way for take different value of each menu item selection by wParam:

```vb
 Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        If m.Msg = &H11F And m.LParam <> HMainMenu Then
            If m.LParam <> 0 Then
                MenuID =(m.WParam.ToInt64 And 255)
                Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Selected.")
            Else
                Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("Clicked. " & MenuID.ToString)
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
```

So with this changes Can have an ID after menuItem clicked But that's not a True ID at Resource DLL.

**How Can I take the True ID of Clicked MenuItem?!!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Code to Get MenuItem ID:

```vb
MenuID = (m.WParam.ToInt64 And &HFFFF&)
```